# In FarCry 3 is there an easier way of finding your kills than stumbling upon the body?

Tags: far-cry-3

I often lose my kills in the grass and brush, even after tagging them with the camera or by aiming at them.  Is there any better way of finding them than having to search?

Even with the flashing texture, I often I can't see it until I'm right on top of the corpse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Other then the bright flashing texture, there is no indication. Roaming around the area looking for the pulsating texture is the best you can do.

Comment: sadly this is the case. Luckily you wont need to hunt for that long to have everything maxed / near maxed out

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to see that. I've only done a couple story missions and I'm up to most of my craftables needing skins from the Hunting side missions.